# PHP imap get colored text

Tags: php, imap

Hi I'm trying to read emails via IMAP. I've wrote a class which works very well. The problem is styled text. e.g. colored text or bold text ...

I try to read the body of a normal email with **imap_fetchbody();** and I recieve the text with new lines and it is displayed correctly but how can i get the color for a line?

Maybe someone can explain to me how the color is stored in an email especially when it's not a HTML-mail.

Thx for your answers.

My Mail structure (**imap_fetchstructure();**):
{"type":0,"encoding":3,"ifsubtype":1,"subtype":"PLAIN","ifdescription":0,"ifid":0,"lines":9,"bytes":538,"ifdisposition":0,"ifdparameters":0,"ifparameters":1,"parameters":[{"attribute":"charset","value":"UTF-8"}]}

Here is a picture of a second mail:
[image]

Comment: It depends on the MIME-type the text body is labelled to be. Most common formats are HTML, RTF and plain text. Plain text does not support coloring text at all. In case your e-mail client shows links in a colored fashion, this is logic implemented in your client, detecting portions of the text that look like a URL and apply formatting

Comment: Thx for reply. I've tested it. I'ver wrote an Email to another client (not in my network and other mailclient). This client could see the colored text but when i try to get the textxtructure it always says that its plain text. the imap server is an HCL Domino Server...a littlebit special maybe...

Comment: i assume the mail is multipart then. it has nothing to do with imap at all

Comment: i really didn't understand this ...the structure of the mail is shown in the question...and when i use imap_fetchmime i recieve this: Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-transfer-encoding: base64

Comment: are you sure you don’t receive an array of parts? maybe what you get is just preview information. to fetch the entire mail i guess there’s another method

Comment: i've added a picture in the question...do you miss something? ... i've used json_encode to display the arrays/objects